# Incredibly slow NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I define the following function
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{\sin x}{\pi \sqrt{\Big[ \cos x - \cos (y-z) \Big] \Big[ \cos (y+z) - \cos (x) \Big]}}
$$
where $y, z$ are all between $0, \pi/2$ and $ |y-z| < x < \text{min}(y+z, \pi/2)$. Additionally, if $y+z > \pi/2$ we reflect the function in the $x$ argument around from $\pi$, $x \to \pi - x$. Thus:
$$
g(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} f (x,y,z); \; &y + z < \pi/2 \\ f (x,y,z) + f (\pi-x,y,z); \; &y + z > \pi/2 \end{cases}
$$

The problem with $g$ is that it has some singularities (all integrable, though).

In Mathematica, I define the function like this

```
test[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x] ((HeavisideTheta[x - Abs[y - z]] HeavisideTheta[y + z - x])/(Pi Sqrt[(Cos[x] - Cos[y - z]) (Cos[y + z] - Cos[x])]) + (HeavisideTheta[y + z - Pi/2] HeavisideTheta[x + y + z - Pi])/(Pi Sqrt[-(Cos[x] + Cos[y - z]) (Cos[y + z] + Cos[x])]));
```

All the thetas are to ensure we don't get any complex numbers from the function. My goal is to do a parametric integral of `test(x,y,z)` multiplied by some simple function of `y` and `z` (no singularities in this additional function) over a square `{y, 0, Pi/2}`, `{z, 0, Pi/2}` with `x` as a parameter.

```
With[{x = Pi/50}, NIntegrate[ Sin[y] Sin[z] test[x, y, z], {y, 0, Pi/2}, {z, 0, Pi/2}]] // Timing
With[{x = Pi/16}, NIntegrate[ Sin[y] Sin[z] test[x, y, z], {y, 0, Pi/2}, {z, 0, Pi/2}]] // Timing
With[{x = Pi/4}, NIntegrate[ Sin[y] Sin[z] test[x, y, z], {y, 0, Pi/2}, {z, 0, Pi/2}]] // Timing
With[{x = 7 Pi/16}, NIntegrate[ Sin[y] Sin[z] test[x, y, z], {y, 0, Pi/2}, {z, 0, Pi/2}]] // Timing
```

Here I took `Sin[y] Sin[z]` as the additional function, as an example.

The timings are absolutely atrocious,

```
{8.26563, 0.0617321}
{7.25, 0.193324}
{5.875, 0.700855}
{7.35938, 0.972718}
```

And I also keep getting the same two errors: `Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.` and `The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.06173208991557969 and 0.0006314495223153685 for the integral and error estimates.` I don't know why I'm getting these, the integral isn't 0, the integrand isn't highly oscillatory and even when I increase the `WorkingPrecision` (tried 16, 50, 100) I still get the same error (but now it takes much more time).

If I try to limit the integration domain to points that already satisfy $ |y-z| < x < \text{min}(y+z, \pi/2)$

```
reg[x_] := ImplicitRegion[(x > Abs[y - z]) && (x < y + z) && (y > 0) && (y < \[Pi]/2) && (z > 0) && (z < \[Pi]/2), {y, z}];
NIntegrate[Sin[y] Sin[z] test[x, y, z], {y, z} \[Element] reg[x]]
```

Now the first integral won't even evaluate (`the integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1},{0.,5.84851*10^-15}}`) and the other three integrals give slightly different results, and, despite limiting the region to even smaller area, the timings are **worse**

```
{8.54688, 0.19472}
{6.92188, 0.704321}
{8.625, 0.97823}
```

The error on the first integral is especially weird, as MMA seems to have make up its own weird domain (the region I specified is not $[0,1] \times [0, 5.84851 \times 10^{-15}]$, where is this number even coming from?)

There are so many weird things happening here, can someone shed some light on it?

Comment: THe weird number comes from Nintegrate trying to resolve an (undetected?) singularity, I think.  NIntegrate works by recursively chopping up parts of the integration domain, when the error estimate on a part is too large. Specifying the singularities/discontinuities usually helps, but I've been unsuccessful as yet.

Comment: It might help to change coordinates to `u == y + z`, `v == y - z`.

Comment: @Goofy I have a bit of a trouble determining the domain I'm integrating over in that case. If I'm doing the algebra right, then we have conditions `u+v = 2y>0`, `u+v < Pi / 4`, `u-v = 2z > 0`, `u - v < Pi/4`. This seems to be a tilted in the u-v world. Should I do it via integral {u, 0, pi/4}, {v, Abs[Pi/8 - u] - Pi/8, Pi/8 - Abs[Pi/8 - u]} (not sure if MMA supports this kind of functional bound), or via region function? Should I also remove the theta functions from the definition, since now it's easier to catch?

Comment: Can you ground your statement "all integrable, though"?

Comment: `HeavisideTheta` stands for the certain distribution, `UnitStep` is the right command here.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the math....

```
With[{x = Pi/50},
  With[{uvint = (* substitute y == u+v, z == u-v *)
     Hold[2 Sin[y]  Sin[z]  test[x, y, z], {y, 0, Pi/2}, {z, 0, 
           Pi/2}] /. {v_, a_, b_} :> a < v < b /. {y -> u + v, 
         z -> u - v} // Apply@List // 
      ReplaceAll[HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep] //
             Echo[#, HoldForm[uvint]] &},
   With[{interval = (* Reduce figures out the new domains *)
      Reduce[Rest[uvint], {u, v}] /. 
        Or | And -> 
         List /. {Verbatim[Inequality][a_?NumericQ, _, v_, _, 
          b_?NumericQ] :> 
         Flatten@{v, 
           NumericalSort@
            Select[{a, b, x/2, Pi/2 - x/2}, a <= # <= b &]},
        Verbatim[Inequality][a_, _, v_, _, b_] :> {v, a, b}
        } //
             Echo[#, HoldForm[interval]] &
     },
    NIntegrate[First[uvint], ##, 
        Exclusions -> { (* help with the singularities *)
          (*2u==Pi/16,2u==Pi-Pi/16,*)
          2 v == x, 2 v == -x}, 
        MaxRecursion -> 20, MinRecursion -> 1, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 20] & @@@ interval // 
     Total
    ]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Still not fast, but convergent and no warnings or errors.